# A Random(r, g ,b) color generator

Tags: javascript, random, colors, generator, rgb

I've just starting to learn JavaScript, So I know only a few things about it. I have searched this question and I found the right code for it that works fine with hexadecimal color format. But before that i was trying sth on my own, Can you help me to turn it to an RGB color generator. Every time  I add this code to my page it won't work.

```js
      document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function() {
        var r =Math.random();
        r = 255*r;
        r = Math.floor(r);

        var g =Math.random();
        g = 255*g;
        g = Math.floor(g);

        var b =Math.random();
        b = 255*b;
        b = Math.floor(b);

        var color= "rgb(" + r +"," + g +"," +b ")";

        document.getElementById("myDiv").style.background: color;
     }
```

Comment: You need to read [ask]

Comment: Just a typo: `background = color;`( `:` to `=`)

Comment: If you use the snippet editor, please provide the full snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax error at missing `+` following `b` at

```
var color= "rgb(" + r +"," + g +"," +b ")";
```

also substitute `=` for `:` at

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.background = color;
```

for

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.background: color;
```

---

```js
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function() {
  var r = Math.random();
  r = 255 * r;
  r = Math.floor(r);

  var g = Math.random();
  g = 255 * g;
  g = Math.floor(g);

  var b = Math.random();
  b = 255 * b;
  b = Math.floor(b);

  var color = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";

  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.background = color;
}
```

```css
div {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<button id="myButton">click</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `.style.background: color` to `.style.backgroundColor = color` and that should do the trick.

**EDIT**

There's another syntax error in your code. You forgot a `+` after specifying `b` when initializing `color`.